# SharePoint Migration - Company aquisition - Domain changed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, domain, content-migration

Company A has bought company B. Company B SharePoint(2010) data has to be migrated to company A. Now company A is recreating all company B users in their domain.

When we migrate SharePoint content
1.  How does the permissions gets affected?
2.  If SharePoint permissions is affected, do we have to add all the users manually?
3.  What happens to created by and modified by values? Are we going to loose them? Any third party tool will help retaining this values?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you're migrating content, but if you're using a 3rd party tool, you would need to use the tool's user mapping feature (e.g. map DOMB\JDoe to DOMA\JDoe). If using the built-in database attach approach, you would need to use:

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Identity 'i:0#.w|domb\jdoe' -Web http://webUrl #Site Collection where the user is present
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias 'doma\jdoe' -IgnoreSid
```

Either way, this will update the modified/created by and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

A third party tool would help in retaining created/modified by as they generally allow you to build mapping files to map a user from one domain to another. It would also then be able to map permissions properly.

If you don't use a third party tool, then permissions would likely be dropped as it can't validate users, meaning you'd have to go in after the fact and adjust things.

Personal take on this is to make the migration user driven, if possible. Give them access to the areas where they will need to put their stuff, and allow them to migrate what they need themselves, in accordance with any records or retention policies you have. Make the other farm read only, and decommission it at a later date. The last thing you want to do is lift and shift into your environment if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Just updating on the path we took to solve this. We bought a third party tool to migrate the content. We were able to retain the permissions & metadata's like created by, modified by etc